# Proof/Disproof order preserving isomorphism between two sets - $\mathbb Z+\mathbb Q+\mathbb N \cong \mathbb Z+\mathbb Q+\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\mathbb Z+\mathbb Q+\mathbb N \cong \mathbb Z+\mathbb Q+\mathbb Z $ ? (preserving isomorphism between two sets).

**My solution:**

I think the sets are not isomorphic since the first element of $\mathbb N$ has no previous element , but in $\mathbb Q$ each element has no previous element too.

I have no other idea what is the different between these two sets.

I'd be grateful for some help/hint.

Comment: The meaning of isomorphism depends on the context. Are you viewing these as ordered sets, just plain sets?

Comment: What do you mean by $\Bbb Z+\Bbb Q+\Bbb N$? With a very common interpretation of $A+B$ that set is just $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about an order isomorphism between these two sets, viewed as linear orders.

You're almost there. The $0$ element in the copy of $\mathbb{N}$ In the first order has a successor but no predecessor. Does the second order have any element with a successor but no predecessor?

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ has successor and predecessor , $\mathbb Q$ has no successor and no predecessor, $\mathbb N$ has successor and no predecessor! Thank you !